# Using Spring StoredProcedure class to call a function

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I am attempting to make a call to an Oracle DB function using Java and Spring. There are many examples out there.   This code base is using Spring version 4.2.13.RELEASE.  Here is my code:

```
    public void someMethod(Long oldUserId, Long newUserId, String loginId, Long profileId) throws Exception
   {
    class MyFunction extends StoredProcedure
    {
        public MyFunction (DataSource ds)
        {
            setDataSource(ds);
            setFunction(true);
            setSql("myschema.f_m_user");
            // this function takes 4 input arguments and returns 1 output parameter.
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("par_login_id", Types.VARCHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("par_old_user_id", Types.NUMERIC));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("par_new_user_id", Types.NUMERIC));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("par_user_profile_id", Types.NUMERIC));
            declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("returnValue", Types.VARCHAR)); 
            compile();
        }

        public String execute(String parLoginId, Long parCurUserId, Long parNewUserId, Long parProfileId)
        {
            //Map inParams = new HashMap();
            //inParams.put("par_login_id", parLoginId);
            //inParams.put("par_old_user_id", parCurUserId);
            //inParams.put("par_new_user_id", parNewUserId);
            //inParams.put("par_user_profile_id", parProfileId);
            //Map result = execute(inParams);
            Map result = super.execute(parLoginId, parCurUserId, parNewUserId, parProfileId);
            String errorMsg = null;
            if (!result.isEmpty() && result.get("returnValue") != null)
            {
                errorMsg = result.get("returnValue").toString();
            }
            return errorMsg;
        }
    } // end class

    MyFunction func = new MyFunction (ds);
    String errorMsg = func.execute(
        loginId,
        oldUserId,
        newUserId,
        profileId);
    if (errorMsg != null)
    {
        throw new Exception(errorMsg);
    }
}
```

This is not working for me because the parameters passed to the DB function are not in the order I've specified.  I've tried this 2 different ways.  Calling execute with a Map and calling execute (see code) with a variable number of arguments.  Surprisingly, both methods are unsuccessful for me.  I feel like I'm missing something simple or the Oracle side has an issue with the function declaration.  Below is the signature for the Oracle function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.f_m_user
-- Returns the oracle error message
(
par_login_id        IN profile.login_id%TYPE,
par_old_user_id     IN profile.user_id%TYPE,
par_new_user_id     IN profile.user_id%TYPE,
par_user_profile_id     IN profile.mod_profile_id%TYPE
)

RETURN VARCHAR2

IS

BEGIN … more code not shown
```

The DB function does get called but arguments passed are out of order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.  Apparently, the order of the declareParameter(…) statements is important.  I guess I missed this information in the docs.  The corrected code is:

```
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("returnValue", Types.VARCHAR)); 
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("par_login_id", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("par_old_user_id", Types.NUMERIC));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("par_new_user_id", Types.NUMERIC));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("par_user_profile_id", Types.NUMERIC));
        compile();
```

I moved the returnValue statement before the in parameters.  I was able to figure this out by building another example but using a prepareCall which looks like this:

```
stmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call utility.f_m_user(?,?,?,?) }");
```

This worked.  Since the return value is specified first here it was a good tip I needed to do the same for the Spring `StoredProcedure` example.